# How can a make a ball move around an object?

Tags: processing

In the following program i want the ball to move around the circle and never through it. The ball should always be following the mouse and should never stop moving. Any help? Thanks.

```
PVector position = new PVector(0,0);
PVector velocity = new PVector();

void setup()
{
  size(600,600);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  ellipse(width/2,height/2,100,100);
  ellipse(position.x,position.y,20,20);

  float angle = atan2(mouseY - position.y, mouseX - position.x);
  velocity = new PVector(cos(angle), sin(angle));
  velocity.mult(5);
  position.add(velocity);

  if(dist(width/2,height/2,position.x,position.y) < 100)
  {
    position.add(new PVector(0,5));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this. It really depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

At its most basic, you could just use the dist() function like you're trying, but instead of always adding (0,5) to the position, make it move *away* from the circle.

You could also look into something called **potential fields**. Google is your friend, but basically, use the position of the circle and the position of the mouse to weight each position on the screen. The closer the position is to the circle, the more weight you give to moving *away* from the circle. The further the position is from the mouse, the more weight you give to moving *towards* the mouse.

Also, consult the examples that comes with the Processing editor. There are several examples on doing collisions between circles.